# Eclipse: JSTL Validation: Confused About Warning Message: "empty" only for collections>

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, string

I just migrated to Eclipse 3.7.2 from another IDE.   I'm maintaining a legacy webapp.

Everything compiles and runs fine.

Eclipse has given me two validation warnings on a JSTL conditional.  It is telling me I can only use "empty" on collections.  Googling people are using it for strings too.

The conditional

```
<c:if test = "${employee_record.show_pcell == 'T' && not empty employee_record.phone_contact_1 }">
    <tr>
        <td id = "fieldLabel">Personal Cell Phone:</td>
        <td>${employee_record.phone_contact_1} </td>
    </tr>
 </c:if>
```

employee_record is a HashMap of all string values

Here are the two warning messages in regards to the conditional.

```
This empty expression always evaluates to false.  Only string, maps, arrays and collection have meaningful values for the empty operator

This not will always result a value of true
```

Comment: If the application executes and goes fine even with these warnings, then keep the work. Sometimes Eclipse IDE shows me strange warnings on JSP about tags not well formed or similar but they indeed are =\

Comment: You're also using an older version.  Perhaps a newer version would do better.

Comment: You mean a newer version of Eclipse?

Comment: EL validation in Eclipse is an epic fail. Just disable it.

Comment: I went to Windows > Preferences > Validation.  I did not see the label "EL Validation".  Is it labeled as something else?

Answer (score -1):

You need to go in Window -> Preferences -> Web -> JavaServer Faces.